# "ctrl+space" has been bound to invoke some input method and does not work in Emacs or Eclipse auto-complete

Tags: shortcut-keys, ibus, input-language

In Emacs run in terminal, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> is a standard shortcut key to select region. But under Ubuntu 12.04, it will invoke some input method for non-English language. I was wondering if I can reserve it for Emacs only?

Under `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts`, I couldn't find to what <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> has been bound. Strange.

Other programs, especially auto-complete in Eclipse, also seem to have a problem handling <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

Answer (score 118):

It sounds like you have Ibus running, which uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> by default to enable/disable the input editor.

You can change the shortcut key assigned to it in Ibus Preferences.

[image]

If Ibus is running in the menubar, you can right-click to choose *Preference* from the menu. If Ibus is not running in the menubar, you can start the Preferences dialog from the Dash by running *Keyboard Input Methods* or from the terminal with `ibus-setup`.

**Update for 14.04**

`ibus-setup` is no longer available for 14.04. Functions from the former `ibus-setup` are instead integrated into *System Settings >> Text Entry*.

Input switching is now set by default to <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, but Ibus may still steal focus from the <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> keybinding and cause other system problems, most notably the auto-complete in Eclipse.

Integration of Ibus input switching into the new Text Entry settings is still a work in progress, and this is causing the problem since the older setting still exists behind the scenes.

If you have upgraded from 12.04, `ibus-settings` should still be available.

In 14.04, you can edit the settings directly is `dconf-editor`.

If it is not installed:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then browse to *Desktop >> ibus >> general >> hotkey*. The `trigger` and `triggers` setting will still show 'control+space'. Edit these settings out, being careful to leave empty brackets `[]` in `triggers`.

Comment: This also fixed autocomplete not working in Eclipse after I upgraded to xubuntu 14.04

Comment: My `ibus-setup` on 14.04 is slightly different and does not have that option.

Comment: @BoppreH 14.04 has changed ibus setup a little. I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @BoppreH 13.10 and 14.04 use super+space for input switching. Are still having trouble using ctrl-space in emacs?

Comment: @chaskes Not emacs, eclipse, but it's the same problem. Started with the 14.04 upgrade and I've checked `Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts` and the shortcut is not there either. Here's what my `ibus-setup` looks like: http://i.imgur.com/sJM1utb.png . For some reason left `alt` is also stealing focus and I don't know why.

Comment: `dconf-editor` fixed my problem, thank you very much @chaskes .

Comment: @BoppreH Glad it worked out. Please upvote (if you haven't done so). ;)

Comment: This fixed the problem, I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Not sure why this isn't accepted as the answer, because this worked for me on Lubuntu 14.04. On a side-note I had to go to `Desktop>>ibus>>general>>hotkey` instead of straight from `ibus` to `hotkey`

Comment: +1 I wish I could give you more up-votes! I just chased my tail for days. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. :)

Comment: This fixed a problem I was having when running emacs in the terminator terminal (not sure why it never happened in other terminals).

Comment: Worked for me on  Android Studio running on Xubuntu

Comment: I've just run into this with a newly installed Ubuntu 14.04.3.  Neither Ctrl-Space nor Ctrl-@ sends a null character in xterm or gnome-terminal. The problem still exists after deleting the "Next input method" setting in IBus Preference and all modifier-Space hotkeys in dconf-editor (desktop > ibus > general > hotkey).

Comment: Correction: After trying both this and Eyal's solution of removing `ibus` altogether, I *am* getting a null character when I type Ctrl-Space. I just wasn't seeing it when I typed Ctrl-V Ctrl-Space in bash.

Answer (score 12):

Disable the IBUS trigger using the commandline:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.general.hotkey triggers @as []
```

Or if this does not work try if the first one produces an error:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.general.hotkey triggers []
```

Comment: The second command worked for me on a corporate customized version of Ubuntu 14.04 (goobuntu), which fixed my emacs problem copy/yank or copy/paste.

Comment: The second command fixed this for me, and it is now in my install script for setting up newly installed ubuntu desktops. Thanks, askubuntu!

Answer (score 6):

ibus causes me nothing but headaches.  Everytime that I try to change the settings, when I reboot, the Ctrl+Space comes back.  Here's my solution:

```
sudo apt-get purge ibus
sudo killall ibus
```

Now everything works until Ubuntu decides their next stupid thing.  Maybe the letter 'o' will map to turning off the computer?

Comment: I just tried this (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS). It didn't help.

Comment: CORRECTION: Either this, or changing the IBus preferences, or running `dconf-editor`, **did** work. I was testing by typing Ctrl-V Ctrl-Space in bash; for some reason bash wasn't accepting it. But Ctrl-Space is generating a null character.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrade to ubuntu 14.04, I had the same problem. What I did.
In Ibus preferences:
`System > Preferences > Keyboard Input Methods`.
There is an option: `Next input method` it was set to ctrl+space, I removed that and then all started to work back again.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Studio 14.04 (XFCE) here.
I didn't have problem with Autocomplete (`Ctrl + Space`), but with Copy Line (`Ctrl + Alt + Down`).

This worked for me:

- Open Windows Manager: `xfwm4-settings`
- Go to Keyboard tab
- Scroll down to conflicting Action
- Hit Clear button or change action to different shortcut

Comment: Thanks!  This can be done on command line, too `xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -r -p " /xfwm4/custom/<Primary><Alt>Up" ; 
xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -r -p " /xfwm4/custom/<Primary><Alt>Down" ; 
xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -r -p " /xfwm4/custom/<Primary><Alt>Left" ; 
xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -r -p " /xfwm4/custom/<Primary><Alt>Right"` .

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 GNOME with LXDE. Apparently this desktop has ibus-setup. So, for me, changing the ibus setting was the right fix. Perhaps it was only Unity that did away with the ibus-setup app.

Comment: Yes, it's a Unity thing.

Answer (score 0):

The `dconf-editor` change was not sufficient for me. I have the Mozc (Japanese) input source installed.

On Ubuntu 16.04, I also had to:

1. Go to System Settings -> Text Entry
2. Click Mozc to highlight
3. Click the wrench/screwdriver icon below
4. Global Config tab
5. The first setting there, "Trigger Input Method," was CTRL_SPACE. I clicked it and then hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> to unset the keybinding.

Answer (score 0):

For some people using Japanese input with fcitx, check `Fcitx Configuration`. There's a menu for global configuration, and under `Trigger Input Method`, the default shortcut will be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.