# Ubuntu - shortcut Ctrl + Space causes conflict in eclipse

Tags: keyboard, eclipse, shortcuts

After I updated ubuntu a new keyboard shortcut appears:

CTRL + SPACE

And I use that shortcut in eclipse to complete commands, and is very practical.

Rather than complete the command appears to me a window to switch the keyboard layout (pt_br Brasil or en_us USA). My keyboard layout uses the Brazilian and I do not want to change.

But I want to know if you have to change this shortcut to not give more conflict with eclipse.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You hit one of the most popular bug in newest Ubuntu. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322 and some ideas in http://askubuntu.com/questions/360378/how-to-access-the-keyboard-layout-options-in-13-10

Comment: @Rmano I don't think this is a bug, see my answer.

Comment: It depends on which shortcut the OP will choose...

Comment: Are you using 13.10?

Comment: It's 14.04 Alpha :|

Comment: Confirmed to happen in the official release too, but I can't vote to reopen the question.

Comment: General problem affecting many applications, see http://askubuntu.com/q/243639.

Answer (score 9):

Open System Settings and go to "Text Entry" change the keys under "Switch to next source using:" to some other keys.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it did not. It seems strange, but I did exactly like the picture and the problem persists.

Comment: @Patterson You may need to restart after applying the changes. Did you do that? Also try changing *both* shortcuts.

Comment: So I rebooted! In the settings of this keyboard shortcut set to Ctrl + Alt + Space. but did not change anything when I press Ctrl + Space it still shows the option to change the keyboard layout.

Comment: @Patterson I would change it to something unrelated to Ctrl and Space personally. Not sure that will fix anything though. It all depends on how the system manages the shortcuts.

Comment: It did not work!

Comment: It`s not Ctrl+Space but Super+Space here and I have the same problem. Changing both hotkeys doesn`t fix the problem.

Comment: Nice, worked also for xubuntu for me where there is also an ap related to ibus in the taskbar. The app looks like a keyboard with a globe icon or via command line: ibus-setup

Comment: Try also `sudo gnome-control-center` and change settings there and possibly from the Layout Settings > System tab > Copy Settings... button.

Comment: In ubuntu+cinnamon: Goto Menu > "Keyboard Input Methods" > Tab "General" > "Next Input Method ...". Then remove the shortcut assigned using "Delete"