# Unbinding Alt in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys

After upgrading to 14.04 my Ubuntu started capturing <kbd>Alt</kbd> for window menu focus. This hides Guake when I type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, for example, and takes away the focus of many text fields.

This shortcut is not listed in `Preferences`-> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts`. How do I disable it?

Comment: I removed the part about Ctrl+Space because it turned out to be unrelated. If you are having problems with it, check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/243639/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> binding can be changed in CCSM

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

[image]

Comment: I'll only be able to test this solution tomorrow, but it seems good. Don't worry about the `Ctrl>+Space` issue, it's been fixed thanks to http://askubuntu.com/questions/243639/ .

Comment: Thanks, it's working. You have to click on "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" within the `ccsm` tool.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Turns out the Ctrl+Space shortcut was unrelated, so I removed it from the question.