# The Ctrl space does not set mark in Emacs

Tags: shortcut-keys, emacs

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and use fvwm as the windows manager. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> does not set mark in Emacs. It seems that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does nothing. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to go to the console, and Emacs works correctly there.  If I use the Ubuntu default windows manager, emacs also works correctly. 
Does anyone have ideas what could be wrong?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You might want to update the title as it's not specific to fvwm. I had the same problem with awesome-wm as well.

Comment: @LesterCheung yep, it is a problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and emacs. (I use KDE for eg.)

Comment: General problem affecting many applications, see http://askubuntu.com/q/243639.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had this same issue and it looks like it's a problem with ibus. From the commandline run: `ibus-setup`

Under `General::Next Input Method` you should see `<Control>space`. Click on the three dots and change it to something else. Hit `Apply` and close out. ctrl-space should work in Emacs now.

Comment: OMG!, Ubuntu (or whatever is going on) should not override such a basic editing command in Emacs!

Comment: @brady-trainor Although ctrl-space is very important for emacs users it is unused by the majority of ubuntu users and having a nice global shortcut for switching language is important, too, at least for non-english users.

Answer (score 0):

For kubuntu users:

- go Global shortcut
- add this control+space shortcup to any (undefined) action , (ie: keymap switcher)
- then a popup will tell there is a conflict with other definition
- confirm to reassign
- delete shortcut