# How do I disable keyboard shortcut for Launcher in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, eclipse

Several of the keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) conflict with Eclipse shortcuts in 14.04.

How do I disable these keyboard shortcuts?

I do not see any options for these specific shortcuts under Keyboard.

Comment: For ctrl+space, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243639/ctrlspace-has-been-bound-to-invoke-some-input-method-and-does-not-work-in-ema) ... but what is ctrl+shift/f doing for you?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Ubuntu Studio 14.04 (XFCE):

- Open Windows Manager: `xfwm4-settings`
- Go to Keyboard tab
- Scroll down to conflicting Action
- Hit Clear (Backspace) button or change action to different shortcut