# Android Studio shortcuts are not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, android-studio

I use Android Studio in Ubuntu and everything was working fine. Since two weeks that shortcuts stopped working, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. I tried to change `Keymap` in `Settings` but without success.

What could be the possible problem?

Comment: Not sure if this is the same issue, but my ctrl+space in eclipse stopped working the other day. As it turned out Ubuntu had claimed the shortcut for something else and thus eclipse never got it. Is it possible Ubuntu has hijacked these shortcuts from you?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77140 I reported as a bug here.

Answer (score 4):

you need to change or disable some of the keyboard shortcuts and iBus preferences in ubuntu, In order to make your IDE keyboard shortcuts to work properly.

for keyboard shortcuts you can go to:

```
System settings-> keyboard -> shortcuts
```

and change or remove the shortcuts accordingly and for ibus preferences you can search ibus in search bar and open `keyboard input methods`.

check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243639/ctrlspace-has-been-bound-to-invoke-some-input-method-and-does-not-work-in-ema) question for other options.